# What is causing my computer to constantly restart?

Tags: crash, onedrive

For the last week or so my computer has randomly restarted about once a day. Below is the crash report. Does this say that OneDrive is causing the crash?

I'm using a 2018 MacBook Pro, running OS 12.4.

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800b71cd6b):  initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 7 subcode 0x1 description: overflow of service activation count during activate. Managed:1. Count:32767. Service:'user/501/com.apple.xpc.launchd.unmanaged.OneDrive File P.1234'

uuid info:
 0x108da8000    uuid = <d52102ca-7c21-349b-848b-6074333dc0d6>
 0x11325e000    uuid = <b70ce1ec-b902-3852-8268-05de00bfa8d5>

Thread 1 crashed

RAX: 0x0000000002000209, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x000070000a4b6258, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0x000070000a4b6258, RBP: 0x000070000a4b62a0, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0x0000000000000007
R8:  0x00007fa201bd7520, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000246
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0x0000000000000007
RFL: 0x0000000000000246, RIP: 0x00007ff812e51dba, CS:  0x0000000000000007, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff90b6931540
    0x00007ff812e341d2
    0x00007ff812cc57f7

Thread 1: 0xffffff90b4fe0540
    0x00007ff812e51dba
    0x00007ff812e53827
    0x0000000108ddc4c7
    0x0000000108db7972
    0x0000000108de87ef
    0x0000000108dd3853
    0x0000000108dcd11b
    0x0000000108dd249b
    0x0000000108de26b8
    0x0000000108de2947
    0x0000000108de2820
    0x00007ff812cb43b1
    0x00007ff812ccd041
    0x00007ff812cba1cd
    0x00007ff812ccdb77
    0x00007ff812cba1cd
    0x00007ff812cbadfd
    0x00007ff812cc4eee
    0x00007ff812e67fd0
    0x00007ff812e66f57

Thread 2: 0xffffff90b4e94540
    0x00007ff812e3005a
    0x00007ff812e66f57

Thread 3: 0xffffff90b641f540
    0x00007ff812e3005a
    0x00007ff812e66f57


Mac OS version:
21F79

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:22 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 3C587984-4004-3C76-8ADF-997822977184
System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
System shutdown begun: NO
```

Comment: See [this Answer at Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-cause-panic-on-mac/53111c30-8120-433d-b78b-14924ab1cb43) which appears to touch on the problem you are experiencing.